# Correct way to process giant lines with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm a bit into a dilemma on 'how to process giant lines of file with Multiprocessing'. In the plan, I will send a `requests` for each line. The file contains a giant list of Subdomain consist of 1-10 Million line, altho the file size is under 1 GB but I worried that my Implementation are going to exhaust my Memory.

I'm using `Queue()` to distribute the task to each process. Here's what I do:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue

tasker = Queue()
with open(processor, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tasker.put(line.strip())
```

The `Multiprocessing` will eventually slow-down, so it must be because of `Queue()` are growing faster than the process could complete. As for Alternative, I use `itertools.islice()` function that will produce 4 task and then Immediately consume it.

```
from itertools import islice
from multiprocessing import Queue

tasker = Queue()
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        liner = [line] + list(islice(f, 4))
        for i in liner:
            tasker.put(str(re.sub('\n', '', i.strip())))
```

Finally, the `Multiprocessing` are running in a reasonable time without Slowing Down but it creates a list containing 4 item that will be appended into the `Queue()` until the list Empty. So it's kinda putting items from 1 list into another list, weird, I know.

Is there a better way to handle this without stressing too much Memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two code snippets are equivalent in the produced output, the second one is only slower, and is only fixing the problem by "stalling the CPU".

the correct way to limit the memory usage is to limit the queue itself, the queue accepts its max size as an argument.

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue
max_size = 1000
tasker = Queue(max_size)
```

if the main process tries to put more tasks in it then it will block the main process until the workers finish some of the work, this will be fast and efficient in terms of CPU and memory usage, (the main process will allow workers to use its CPU core to finish some of the work, hence more works gets done, without consuming more memory)

if you don't want the main process to be blocked as it has other things to do then you can have a thread in the main process putting tasks in the queue using the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module

if you want to reduce the overhead of locking the queue, then you should submit work in chunks.

```py
from itertools import islice
from multiprocessing import Queue

max_size = 200  # note: 200 * 5 = 1000
tasker = Queue(max_size)
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        liner = [line] + list(islice(f, 4))
        liner = [x.strip() for x in liner]
        tasker.put(liner)  # put the list of 5 items in the queue
```

and the consumer is expected to loop over the list obtained from the queue and perform each task in the received list independently.

Comment: Hi! is limiting the Queue Max_Size will affect reading file? Let's say that the Line is already traverse at Line 10,000  but the Max_Size is 1000.

Comment: `.put()` will block when there are 1000 items in the queue, so you'll end up reading the file slower.

Comment: @Xavi it just "pauses" the main process if there is "too much tasks in the queue" until some of the tasks are completed then the operating system will "resume" the main process again from exactly where it stopped.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I've been trying the `threading` one, but I don't see any differences. Since it's the same thing but just using thread. Inside `threading`, I do the same as above: ```with open(processor, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tasker.put(line.strip())```, Is there any surplus to this or I'm doing it incorrectly? @AhmedAEK

Comment: @Xavi you might want to try the "chunked" approach i added above to speed up file read and queue access, but figuring out the "slowdown" reason needs profiling, i am only fixing the queue access, and the "slowdown" could be elsewhere, depending on what each "task" does, using threads only allows your main process to do other things while the file is being read, it doesn't speed it up, it only avoids "pausing the main process" if it is doing something as critical as controlling a GUI or something else.